# No "run as administrator" for Local User and Groups

Tags: start-menu, uac, mmc

When I use Windows 10 as a user without admin right (seperate user for this) most of the start menu entries for settings via management console have a right-click action where I can say "start as administrator" and then enter my secondary credentials. However the local user manager console does not have this function. I wonder why that is, and if this can be turned on?

I have a work around, I can start the command (`"%windir%\system32\lusrmgr.msc"`) directly and there I can start it at the admin user, so the absence of this menu option seems not to be a security feature, so why is it there?

Comment: One theory I have is, that if you run the user manager as a local admin it has difficulties to connect to AD and asks for a second user, this can be confusing, so maybe Microsoft decided to not encourage this?

Comment: What is the "management console"?

Comment: `mmc.exe` is the management console to host plugins like the Local User manager.

Answer (score 1):

you can run that with admin privilege by this command:

```
runas /user: domain\admin_account "%SystemRoot%\system32\mmc.exe lusrmgr.msc"
```

Comment: I know, but that was not the question, I wonder how you can turn off the admin menu entry and why it is turned off for one of the more important management star menu entries,